# How to upgrade Extension Library to latest version?

Tags: ibm-domino

My **updatesite.nsf** has the following features:

```
Domino Access Services (DAS)                                          8.5.3.20121217-1354
Domino Wink                                                           8.5.3.20121217-1354
XPages Extension Library Feature                                      8.5.3.20121217-1354
Extended Components Library for XPages Extension Feature              8.5.3.20121217-1354
XPages Extension Library Designer Source Feature                      8.5.3.20121217-1354
XPages Extension Library Designer Feature                             8.5.3.20121217-1354
XPages Extension Library Source Feature                               8.5.3.20121217-1354
Extended Components Library for XPages Extension Feature              8.5.3.20121217-1354
Apache Wink                                                           1.1.2.20121217-1354
```

In **notes.ini** I have this:

> OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=admin/updatesite.nsf

When I restart HTTP I get this message:

> HTTP JVM: CLFAD0330I: NSF Based plugins are being installed in the
>   OSGi runtime. For more information please consult the log

Which log does "please consult the log" refer to?

When I issue console command

```
tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
```

I get this:

```
10 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer_8.5.3.20121217-1354
11 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.feature.source_8.5.3.20121217-1354
12 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.tooling_8.5.3.20121217-1354
13 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.xspprops_8.5.3.20121217-1354
14 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.tooling.feature.source_8.5.3.20121217-1354
15 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.source_8.5.3.20121217-1354
142 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl1_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=145
143 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl2_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=145
144 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl3_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=145
145 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Fragments=142, 143, 144
146 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl1_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=149
147 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl2_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=149
148 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl3_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=149
149 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Fragments=146, 147, 148
150 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl1_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=153
151 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl2_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=153
152 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl3_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=153
153 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Fragments=150, 151, 152
154 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl1_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=157
155 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl2_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=157
156 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl3_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=157
157 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Fragments=154, 155, 156
158 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl1_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=161
159 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl2_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=161
160 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl3_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Master=161
161 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.3.20111208-0717
             Fragments=158, 159, 160
162 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.3.20111208-0717
```

None of these are active at this point. How do I know which version it uses and why are the old versions listed? When I start using XPages the old 2011 versions turn to ACTIVE state and **xpagesext.nsf** gives this error:

> Cannot find the library "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library" with tag version
>   8.5.32001, to be used by the page /Core_InPlaceDialog.xsp. The library tag version is blank.

In my understanding this indicates old ExtLib version. How do I get rid of the old versions and make the new version ACTIVE?

thanks,

- Panu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Upgrade Pack 1 is already installed on the server. Upgrace Pack 1 is version "8.5.3.20111208-0717" (and has no extlibx components).

So you need to uninstall Upgrade Pack 1 and then use the update site method to install extension library.

Comment: I must have installed it at some point although I don't remember doing so. I uninstalled it and got rid of the 2011 versions but the new ones did not activate. I found this "CLFAD0331W: NSF Based plugin contribution denied because signer does not have required access: :admin\updatesite.nsf" from error-log-0.xml. I signed the db a few times and finally realized I had to select "Actions -> Sign All Content" in UpdateSite db with Notes client. That fixed it and the lastest extlib version works now. Thanks!

Comment: Btw. I was expecting Admin client would show "Upgrade Pack 1" like it shows "FP3" and "HF87".